# 260K image files resizing with php

Tags: php

I have 260K image files in a folder.I need to resize them all with php.But there is execution time limit.I think this process will be longer then 60 seconds.

How can I execute this url without any problem ? I am not sure about cronjob is good for this case ? What do you think ?

I am not asking anycode from you. I wrote the code but how can I execute ?

Comment: Ideally, you should do them in batches, I.e. include a GET parameter that specifies what batch you are working on, and then use that GET parameter to only work on images 0-999, 1000-1999, or however you set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot modify the php.ini and your server allows it you can change the timelimit with set function

```
set_time_limit(0); //no limit
```

But if you cannot change the php.ini and your server don't allow to modify it with set function, with cron you will have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize those images only once (you don't want to do it frequently), you can change the script execution timeout in your server configuration, or run it from the command line or cronjob. An other option is to skip already resized images and continue from where you stopped last time.